# Getting data from multiple tables using a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models below:

```
users
id | First_Name | Last_Name 
1  | abc        | ABC 
2  | mno        | MNO

professions
id | user_id | Designation
1  | 1       | Lead
```

And I have a textbox name `tf_Designation` where I enter Designation for e.g `Lead` and I want to get `user's First_Name and Last_Name` and `profession's Designation` where Designation is equal to `Lead` and I am using the below code for doing it:

```
def search
  if ( !params[:tf_Designation].blank? or params[:tf_Designation] !="" )
    @user_designation = Profession.find(:all, :conditions => ["Designation = ?", params[:tf_Designation]])
  end       

  render 'search'
end
```

That works fine but it gave me designation only but I want also `First_Name` and `Last_Name` from user model. So I tried this:

```
def search
  if ( !params[:tf_Designation].blank? or params[:tf_Designation] !="" )
    @user_designation = Profession.joins(:user).where("professions.Designation = " + params[:tf_Designation] )
  end       

  render 'search'
end
```

But I am getting below error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Lead: SELECT "professions".* FROM "professions" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "professions"."user_id" WHERE (professions.Designation = Lead)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your join. The problem is that you are using `where` incorrectly. You have to use [`where`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) like this:

```
where('professions.Designation = ?', params[:tf_Designation])
```

or

```
where('professions.Designation' => params[:tf_Designation])
```

Your code is wrong because it results in a query without quotes around *Lead* and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: your post is working fine and give me designation from profession's model but when I want to get First_Name from "user". it gave me error "undefined method `First_Name'" And I am using this code for geting data in view page: {<% @user_designation.each do |desig| %>
            <h1><%= desig.Designation %></h1>
            <h1><%= desig.First_Name %></h1>
            <% end %>}

Comment: You have to do `desig.user.First_Name` to get the first name of your user.